# Split Excel Into Mutliple Workbook Not Active Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Still too much to learn and not very handy in VBA yet, I need to split my excel files into multiple workbook and save in the same folder or if i can browse the folder , i found the code to split the excel sheet into workbook , now my issue is i have put that code into my personcal macro book and upon running this code , it just save my sheets i have in personal macrobook to the folder however i need it to save the files i am running this for.

please help

```
Sub Splitfile()
    Dim xPath As String
    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` in the `For Each` loop. You may want to store the original ActiveWorkbook in a variable first and then use that.

Comment: Thank You so much though i am not very good in it , you mean to say i should remove thisworkbook

Comment: Yeah, and change it to `ActiveWorkbook`. `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code resides in, in your case that would be the personal binary file, `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus (or something like that, it might be a little more complex than that).